# Fantasy book series; Brother is jealous of sister's magical (sword) glove

Tags: story-identification, magical-items

I read a series of books a few years ago but I never finished the series.

The main characters were a brother and sister. The brother was jealous of the sister having put on a glove that does not come off and that summons a sword. Over time the brother learns magic.

The setting is like the Dark Ages(?). 
(edit) If anyone may have read the books, i remember the brother started using (fire?) magic in a mountain made of ice, and when the sister used the glove it would heat up, and would also burn if she tried to pull it off, and she though it was a curse. hopefully that helps.

Comment: Details don't quite match, but the glove makes me think of Jamethiel from P.G. Hodgell's God Stalker series about the Kencyrath.

Comment: yeah, i was trying to fix something and messed something else up, and yeah, i read the series 7 years ago, and forgot the series before finishing, so it will be a bit fuzzy. and i checked, that's not the series.

Comment: It reminds me of A.J. Lake's The Coming of Dragons, but probably isn't the same...

Comment: k, lemme check, it sounds familiar

Comment: YES OH MY GOD YES IT IS THANK YOU SO MUCH. its the darkest age series, i advise you people to read it, its amazing

Comment: @ReillyDuHaime: Now that the answer is posted, if you think it's the right one, please click on the checkmark to accept it. :)

Answer (score 4):

The story is probably *The Coming of Dragons* by A.J. Lake(who is not me...).

> Edmund, a king's son in disguise, and Elspeth, a sea captain's tomboy daughter, are the only two survivors of a terrible shipwreck. They just want to go home, but fate has other plans as they are drawn into the fight against an evil warlord terrorizing their homeland. Accompanied by a mysterious minstrel and haunted by magical powers they did not seek, Edmund and Elspeth journey across a savage land of wild boars, fierce rogue knights, and black magic. Fantasy fans will devour this dramatic tale of mystery, wonder, and the power of friendship.

---

> The main characters were a brother and sister.

The two are not siblings but do become very close friends.

> The brother was jealous of the sister having put on a glove that does not come off and that summons a sword. Over time the brother learns magic.

Edmund has abilities of the Ripente, and can see through other peoples' eyes.  Elspeth has a magical crystal sword that is worn all the time as a glove(and she cannot take it off).

> The setting is like the Dark Ages

The series that the book is from is called The Darkest Age.